# How to convert a map to a slice of entries?

Tags: dictionary, go, slice

I'm trying to convert key-value map to slice of pairs, for example given a map like:

```
m := make(map[int64]int64)
m[521] = 4
m[528] = 8
```

How do I convert that into a slice of its entries, like: `[[521, 4], [528, 8]]`

I'm thinking about ranging over all those key-values then create slice for that, but is there any simple code to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    //create a map
    m := map[int64]int64{512: 8, 513: 9, 234: 9, 392: 0}

    //create a slice to hold required values
    s := make([][]int64, 0)

    //range over map `m` to append to slice `s`
    for k, v := range m {

        // append each element, with a new slice []int64{k, v}
        s = append(s, []int64{k, v})
    }

    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// MapToSlice to convert map[k]v to []struct{field1: k, field2: v.abc, field3: v.def}
func MapToSlice[E comparable, T any, A any](hashmap map[E]T, new func(E, T) A) []A {
    var slice []A
    for k, v := range hashmap {
        slice = append(slice, new(k, v))
    }
    return slice
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/1sssP0lYb17

Answer (score 0):

#### Go 1.18

It is now possible to write a generic function to extract all key-value pairs, i.e. the map entries, with any key and value types.

Notes:

- the map iterations are still unordered — using generics doesn't change that.
- the constraint for the map key [must be comparable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71505556/is-there-a-go-generic-type-constraint-that-captures-the-ability-to-use-a-type-as)

```
type Pair[K, V any] struct {
    First  K
    Second V
}

func Entries[M ~map[K]V, K comparable, V any](m M) []Pair[K, V] {
    entries := make([]Pair[K, V], 0)
    for k, v := range m {
        entries = append(entries, Pair[K, V]{k, v})
    }
    return entries
}
```

The type `Pair` here is used to preserve type safety in the return value. If you really *must* return a slice of slices, then it can only be `[][]any` (or `[][2]any`) in order to hold different types.

If the map key and value have the same type, of course you can still use `Pair` but you can also use a type-safe variation of the above:

```
func Entries[T comparable](m map[T]T) [][2]T {
    entries := make([][2]T, 0)
    for k, v := range m {
        entries = append(entries, [2]T{k, v})
    }
    return entries
}
```

Again, `T` must be `comparable` or stricter in order to work as a map key.

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/RwCGmp7MHKW