# Go generics: type constraint for map keys?

Tags: go, generics, comparable, type-constraints

In the code below, I define a generic linked list. Go1.18 is happy to use an instance of the list as a key to a map. However, the last line, when uncommented, doesn't compile; I get the error:

> Cons[int] does not implement comparable

Is there a weaker type constraint I can use that picks out those types that can be used as keys, or is this intended, or is it a compiler bug?

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type List[X any] interface {
    isList()
}

type Cons[X any] struct {
    Data X
    Next List[X]
}

func (Cons[X]) isList() {}

type Nil[X any] struct{}

func (Nil[X]) isList() {}

func id[X comparable](x X) X { return x }

func main() {
    x := Cons[int]{5, Nil[int]{}}
    m := map[List[int]]string{}
    m[x] = "Hi"        // succeeds
    fmt.Println(m[x])  // prints "Hi"
    // fmt.Println(id(x)) // fails
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Go 1.20 (February 2023)

`comparable` is the correct catch-all constraint for map keys.

All types that are [comparable as per the Go spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Comparison_operators), even if the comparison may panic at run time, can satisfy the `comparable` constraint. Your code will compile as expected in 1.20.

This finally fixes the inconsistency in previous Go version about spec-comparable types vs `comparable` types. See below for details.

#### Go 1.18 and 1.19

The predeclared `comparable` constraint is the correct constraint for map keys, however it can be instantiated only by **strictly comparable** types, i.e. types that support `==` and `!=` (condition for being used as map keys) but won't panic at run time. This **excludes interfaces<sup>1</sup>**.

This is mentioned here: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_constraints

> The predeclared interface type comparable denotes the set of all
> non-interface types that are comparable. Specifically, a type T
> implements comparable if:
>
> - `T` is not an interface type and `T` supports the operations `==` and `!=` <sup>2</sup>
> - `T` is an interface type and each type in `T`'s type set implements `comparable`
>
> Even though interfaces that are not type parameters can be compared (possibly causing a run-time panic) they do not implement comparable.

This is an important gotcha, because basic interface types normally do support the [equality operators](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) — what is compared is their dynamic types/values.

Therefore, your interface `List[X]` can be used as a map key directly, as in `map[List[int]]string{}`, but it does not implement `comparable` because it has an infinite type set (it has no terms, so any type implements it). And `Cons` doesn’t implement it either because it has a field of type `List[X]`. There is no "weaker" constraint for this.

Consider that constraints that embed `comparable` are also valid for map keys, so if you really need the method `isList()` in the function body, you can define a constraint like this, and have your lists-that-are-map-key structs implement that, instead of declaring an interface field:

```
// may use this as a constraint
type List interface {
    comparable
    isList() bool
}
```

---

<sup>1: the quote from the specs hints there are interface types that implement `comparable`, but it's effectively not possible to instantiate `comparable` with any interface at all: interfaces with only methods have an infinite type set, and interfaces with type terms can't be used anywhere except as constraints.</sup>

<sup>2: this rule actually doesn't cover non-interface types that support `==`, like `type S struct { data any }`, but these types still can't instantiate `comparable` https://go.dev/play/p/N-pmE0XC-hB. This is a bug in the spec.</sup>