# What's the difference between types.Implements and types.Satisfies?

Tags: go, types, standard-library

What's the difference between [types.Implements](https://pkg.go.dev/go/types#Implements) and [types.Satisfies](https://pkg.go.dev/go/types#Satisfies) in golang?

I'm working on a code that inspects Go AST.

Comment: Go's type system has two relations: implements for "some type T implements all methods of an interface I" and constraint satisfaction which is "does some type A satisfy the constraints imposed on a type parameter P of a generic type G". (Actually you do not need to know as you do not need to use package types).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want to know more concrete example when they differs. Can some type A "implement" interface I without "satisfy"ing I, or vice versa? Actually, I'm working on Go AST and going to utilize package types.

Comment: For example, `constraints.Integer` is a type constraint which can be satisfied, but it has no methods which could be implemented.

Comment: Thanks so much! Then, types.Implements relates to method implementations and types.Satisfies relates to both method implementations and type constraints, right?

Comment: It probably only makes sense to use `Satisfies` for type constraints, given that the documentation says "`Satisfies` reports whether type V satisfies the _constraint_ T". I guess your confusion is probably because "interfaces" are used for both type constraints during compilation and runtime polymorphism, but serve different purposes in each context.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. The second parameter T has a type `*Interface` but T is a constraint, as the doc suggests. Thank you.

Comment: I found that TypeParam.Constraint() might return Type that isn't *Interface so passing constraint into Satisfies() is not straight forward as I expected...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

A type may "satisfy" `comparable` without "implementing" it, i.e. without belonging to its type set.

---

The method names are directly related to the language specification, so it helps to look at that first:

[Implementing](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Implementing_an_interface) is defined as:

> A type T implements an interface I if
>
> - T is not an interface and is an element of the type set of I; or
> - T is an interface and the type set of T is a subset of the type set of I.

The concept of "type set" is also defined in the specs and depends on what kind of interface you are considering. Basic interfaces are those which include only methods, and the type set is the set of all types that implement those methods, e.g.:

```
// type set includes all types with the method Read (signature must match)
type Reader interface {
    Read([]byte) (int, error)
}
```

Non-basic interfaces are those which include type terms (and zero or more methods), the type set is the set of the specified types. If any term is approximate, e.g. `~int` the set includes types that have `int` as underlying type.

```
// type set includes int, string and anything with int or string as underlying type
type Foo interface {
    ~int | ~string
}
```

[Satisfying](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Satisfying_a_type_constraint) is used only for interface *constraints* and is defined as:

> A type T satisfies a constraint C if
>
> - T implements C; or
> - C can be written in the form interface{ comparable; E }, where E is a basic interface and T is comparable and implements E.

As you can see the definition of "satisfying" includes "implementing" plus an exception.

Before Go 1.20, the concept of "satisfying" an interface — any interface — didn't exist. Every use case was called "implementing".

In Go 1.20 "satisfying" was introduced to expand the definition of "implementing a constraint" with an exception (the second bullet point in the above quote) for types that had to satisfy `comparable`. Before, types such as `reflect.Type` or `[2]io.Reader` didn't implement `comparable` despite supporting `==` and `!=` operators in non-generic code.

In other words, there was a mismatch between the definition of comparable as per the spec, and the actual type set of the `comparable` constraint.

More info: [Go generics: type constraint for map keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71505556/go-generics-type-constraint-for-map-keys/71508007#71508007)